# question on turbo c

Tags: windows

Can anyone tell me which version of turbo c will work on windows 7 and from where to download it free...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920351/what-is-wrong-with-using-turbo-c

Comment: Turbo C is ancient, non-standard and unsupported. Consider using a modern standards-compliant compiler instead.

Comment: You'll need an emulator first, and then you'll need to set up an MS-DOS virtual machine. Try [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). As other answers have mentioned, there are a multitude of problems with using such an old compiler on a new computer, especially if you're running the 64-bit edition of Win 7.

Comment: Don't use Turbo C. I know your teachers made you. But don't anyway.

Comment: On Codeplex https://turboc.codeplex.com

Answer (score 3):

You can download it [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25636). This is from the Embarcadero site; it does require registration before you can download it.

I do not know if you will be able to use this on Windows 7. I recently installed Borland Pascal 7 on a DOS 6.22 VM, just for kicks; the BP7 cannot be run on 64 bit Windows 7.

If you are targeting the windows platform have you considered looking at [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/)? It is free and quite functional.

Comment: +1 if you are on windows platform best IDE would be Microsoft Visual C++ Express

Answer (score 2):

Turbo C will work up to Vista. It will also work in 32 bit editions of Windows 7, in XP or 98 compatibility mode. It will [not work on any 64-bit versions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282423) of Windows.

For 64 bit Windows I recommend [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend **Turbo C**. It's obsolete.

#### Reasons

- Produces 16bit applications which dosen't work in modern OS.
- The code is **DOS** specific.
- Autocomplete not supported.
- Dosen't support modern **C++** syntax.
- The project is discontinued.

I recommend [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/). It's good for programming.

> **That said,** [Turbo C](https://developerinsider.co/download-turbo-c-for-windows-7-8-8-1-and-windows-10-32-64-bit-full-screen/) is still downloadable.

Comment: Can you say why you think Turbo C is obsolete?

Comment: It produces 16bit applications. Which can't be executed in modern computers.
The code is **DOS** specific. It don't have autocomplete feature.
Doesn't support modern C++ syntax. The project is discontinued.

Comment: I'm convinced!  Thank your for elaborating.

Comment: Turbo C produces, 16-bit DOS specific code, which in modern computers can't be run. Since Windows 7 or so Microsoft discontinued supporting 16-bit applications, also nor GNU/Linux's `wine` can emulate with this kind of architecture.

Yes, that was I two years ago @MaxvonHippel.

Answer (score 1):

Turbo C can not be used to target Windows 7. You may be able to run your Turbo C program in a compatibility mode but, unless there's a newer version I'm unaware of, you won't even be able to do that on Windows 7 64-bit.